# Look for Date values in embedded in strings

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup, microsoft-excel-365

I have a value in a cell that might have a 2-digit month and 2-digit year value embedded in it, and I need a function that would return TRUE if that is found.

Sample input data: `sCa!1220LB6qHZbCnsEE`  where `1220` would be for December 2020, and the formula should return true for that input.

Sample range of "valid" digits to look at:

```
0120
0220
0320
0420
0520
0620
0720
0820
0920
1020
1120
1220
```

Reason: A certain company has some fairly complex password rules, to the point I have a spreadsheet to count things like number of UPPER CASE characters, lower case characters, certain special characters, etc.  Well, they just added a check for a password like `password0620` that has `0620` in it, for June 2020.  If found, they reject the password.

I remember a end-user at a large company decades ago, that alternated her password between `SPRING`, `SUMMER`, `AUTUMN`, and 'WINTER`!

I do have access to the [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) and [XMATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xmatch-function-d966da31-7a6b-4a13-a1c6-5a33ed6a0312) functions, but I am not sure if those would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Match to check:

```
 =OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&E1:E12&"*",A1,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  I couldn't wrap my head around that array magic.  Works perfect.